# Where is the Java EE installation directory on OS X 10.8?

Tags: jakarta-ee, installation, osx-mountain-lion

How can I find the Java EE installation directory after installing it?

My `JAVA_HOME` is empty. I am working on *Mac OS X Mountain Lion*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command to check if you find it:

```
ls -l /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
```

Other paths may be used but you'll probably find the jdk at that path. If not, you can try this:

```
ls -l /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
```